# LINQ - Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, contains, iqueryable

This seems to be about the most generic error I've come across - multiple SO posts about it are all referring to different issues - well here's a new one :)

I get the error above when the following `IQueryable` is enumerated:

**N.B. `items` is an `IQueryable<tblItem>` and `keywords` is a `string`**

```
items = items.Where(p => p.heading.ToLower().Contains(keywords) || 
                         p.description.ToLower().Contains(keywords));
```

This is confusing because, as the error suggests, it should work fine when you use a `Contains` - does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your `where` statement is OK. I have just tryed similar query with LinqPad and NorthWind DB. As @sgmoore stated, problem is probably in `items` `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Thanks sgmoore for your input - it helped arrive at this solution:

Assgning the `IQueryable` list to an `IEnumerable` list, running a `ToList` on it and THEN using my filters on the list worked great.

```
IEnumerable<tblItems> temp = items.ToList();

temp = temp.Where(p => p.heading.ToLower().Contains(keywords) || 
                     p.description.ToLower().Contains(keywords));

items = temp.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: As long as your are ok with getting everyting in tblItems table into memory and performing in memory filtering.

Answer (score 2):

If keyword is a collection that supports enumeration, then it should be other way around:

```
items = items.Where(p => keywords.Contains(p.heading.ToLower()) || 
                         keywords.Contains(p.description.ToLower()));
```

Comment: If keywords is a collection @Jimbo's code would not even compile.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It'll be helpfull to get type for keywords variable.

Comment: Apologies, `keywords` is a `string`

Comment: Then code that you provided is correct and equvalent to

`items = items.Where(p => p.heading.ToLower() == keywords || 
                         p.description.ToLower() == keywords);`

Comment: @Eugene: Not true - `Contains` will test if the keywords are a *substring* of a string - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If items is IQueryable then the error may be there and nothing to do with your where statement. 
Can you try forcing enumeration before adding your where statement?

For example, suppose you are attempting to join an in memory list with a datatable you will get that error when the query is evaluated or enumerated

```
List<tblCategory> categories = tblCategory.ToList();

IQueryable<tblItem> items = (from r in tblItem 
            join c in categories on r.CategoryID equals c.Id select r);


//    items = items.Where(p => p.heading.ToLower().Contains(keywords) || 
//                             p.description.ToLower().Contains(keywords));



var firstMatch = items.FirstOrDefault();

// The error will be generated here even if the where is remmed out
```